# Parse localDataStore is not deleted when app is deleted?

Tags: ios, parsing, pfobject

Should the Parse (iOS) localDataStore be deleted when an app is deleted?  I've been testing on my device as well as in the simulator and it certainly appears that Pinned objects remain on the device even when the app is deleted and the re-installed.

Is there anyway to ensure the localDataStore gets cleared if/when an app is deleted?

Comment: Have you deleted the code that pins the objects before reinstalling? It could just be your pinning them again not that they remain there

Comment: This is not the case. When the app starts the first thing it does is look for a pinned object and only creates one if none are found.  When you delete the app you would expect all locally pinned data is also deleted.